# Impossible to import flask_cors with apache2, mod_wsgi under Python3.5 on a Raspberry pi

Tags: apache, flask, pip, raspberry-pi3, wsgi

I try to setup a website based on Flask on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, with Apache2 (2.4.25), and mod_wsgi, but I am unable to import the module flask_cors in Python3.5...

I installed mod_wsgi with the command `ssudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`

Because I only plan on using the Raspberry for hosting my website, I tried to install the packages needed by Flask system-wide, with the version 3.5 of Python, with the following command: `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` where requirements.txt is the following:

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.3
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
six==1.11.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
Requests==2.20.0
```

I think I understood that on a Raspi, it is best to import the modules wit the command `pip3 install -U <module>` because the packages are not installed on the default location for python, which is confirmed in my case by the following command `python -m site` that yields the following information:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv-16.1.0-py3.5.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/pi/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

My Flask and dependencies are indeed installed in the `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` folder. But this does not seem to be a problem because when checking for importing on a python shell, everything seems fine systemwide:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask_cors import CORS
>>>
```

Knowing that, I tried to put the following files to setup my apache server:

flaskregul.conf in the folder /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskregul/flaskregul.wsgi
    Alias /static/ /var/www/flaskregul/dist/static/
    <Directory /var/www/flaskregul/dist/static>
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskregul
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/flask.monnomdedomaine.com.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

flaskregul.wsgi in /var/www/flaskregul:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flaskregul") # path to my __init__.py file
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages") # path to the site-packages folder where the modules are installed by pip3
from __init__ import app as application
```

__init__.py in /var/www/flaskregul:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
```

I encounter an impossibilty to specifically import the flask_cors module, because the launching of the file __init__.py yields the following errors in the file `/var/log/apache2/flask.monnomdedomaine.com.log`:

```
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.220394 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550] mod_wsgi (pid=6804): Target WSGI script '/var/www/flaskregul/flaskregul.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.220972 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550] mod_wsgi (pid=6804): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/flaskregul/flaskregul.wsgi'.
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.221936 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.222365 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550]   File "/var/www/flaskregul/flaskregul.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.222395 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550]     from __init__ import app as application
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.222445 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550]   File "/var/www/flaskregul/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.222463 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550]     from flask_cors import CORS
[Sat Nov 10 00:37:22.222557 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6804:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.67:33550] ImportError: No module named 'flask_cors'
```

Whereas the import of Flask seems fine...

I've tried to debug this by changing the WSGI script file by this one:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flaskregul")
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages")

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    output = u''
    output += u'sys.version = %s\n' % repr(sys.version)
    output += u'sys.prefix = %s\n' % repr(sys.prefix)
    output += u'sys.path = %s\n' % repr(sys.path)

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output.encode('UTF-8')]
```

This is a piece of advice the advice on this web page from mod_wsgi: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html. When opening the webpage, I obtain this result:

```
sys.version = '3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) \n[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]'
sys.prefix = '/usr'
sys.path = ['/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/var/www/flaskregul', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv-16.1.0-py3.5.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I have the impression that the path is correct! I actually succeed in importing my own modules located in the /var/www/flaskregul location...

I am lost, I don't understand why specifically the module flask_cors is unavaiblable, because it is indeed in the path:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages $ l | grep flask
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi pi   4096 nov.   9 23:30 flask
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi   4096 nov.  10 00:08 flask_cors
pi@raspberrypi:~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages $ l flask_cors 
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 13771 nov.  10 00:08 core.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  4937 nov.  10 00:08 decorator.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  7405 nov.  10 00:08 extension.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi   924 nov.  10 00:08 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi  4096 nov.  10 00:08 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    22 nov.  10 00:08 version.py
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! I am currently losing my hair at a worriyng rate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god I solved it in a desperate try before giving up.

I executed the following commands on a shell: (pip is the pip of the python3.5 /!\)

```
pip uninstall flask
pip uninstall flask_cors
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
hash -d pip
sudo pip install -U flask
sudo pip install -U flask_cors
```

Website up and running! :D